# LotusScript How get MD5 or SHA-1 from NotesStream

Tags: md5, lotusscript, sha, lotus

I use Lotus Domino

I need to get a checksum for class NotesStream how to do it on LotusScript without using Java?

It can by MD5 or SHA-1

Can eat what that LotusScript function?

If it does not work out, then you have to use JavaSession.

```
NotesStream->Base64->JavaSession->SHA-1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation of SHA-1 in LotusScript: [NCT1_SHA1_PROVIDER_CLASS.LSS](http://www.thenorth.com/apblog4.nsf/0/4658893B587F929B852576F000662499). And there's also [MD5 implementation for Lotus Script](http://wwwendt.de/tech/md5/)

It took about 2 minutes to find these in Google.

Comment: Thanks for the information, apparently at the time of writing the question, I still correctly formulated my request